# Need to add variables into Iframes URL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

lets simply explain what I need to do.
I receive from my DB two coordinates, which should be added to iframes URL.
Let show you example:
I receive into my html page two coordinates of one point: x=39.85346 y=28.36137
Then I have iframe which consist of some url: http://www.xxxx.yy/xxxx.htm#zoom=19&**x=39.85346**&**y=28.36137**&layers_3=0B0000FFFTFT&**yon=28.36137**&**x=39.85346**
I need to create some variables inside of my iframes URL (strong) to create iframe which is changed based on points from DB.
I hope question is clear.
Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assumed your variables as $x,$y,$xon,$yon,$layers
and x is repeated twice in url,it has to be different.

Try below code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.xxxx.yy/xxxx.htm#zoom=19&x=<?php echo $x; ?>&y=<?php echo $y;?>&layers_3=<?php echo $layers;?>&yon=<?php echo $yon; ?>&xon=<?php echo $xon;?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked..